# Oracle 11g database tables dropped

Tags: database, oracle

Some of my oracle database tables are dropped.
i don't know how that some one dropped it by logging in database or it was some hacking attack.So, some one please suggest me how can i check or what are the possiblities in this case.
*in any of my procedures or function drop query is not used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `show recyclebin`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables011.htm#i1011340

Comment: Is there an application connected to your db? If so then I would guess you're a victim of an [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

Comment: Or someone just typed "drop table ...", it happens and is a simpler explanation.

Comment: Of course it would be a simpler explanation, but it seems they guy is clueless on who did that (probably he works alone). So i'm just guessing how that happened.

Comment: Of course, you make backups, correct?